# Compile and link sources from different directories with make and gcc

Tags: c++, c, gcc, makefile

I`m having a Project with some subdirectories. I want to compile them with one makefile per Directory and link all Output files into one executable. Can anyone explain me, which commands I should use (-c or -g or extra call)?

makefile in my root-directory:

```
LIBS = 

# The test will be called in this file. There is no need to change this.
#SRCS = main_test.c
SRCS = min.c max.c

###############################################################################
#                                                                             #
#   Normally it is not needed to edited below this.                           #
#                                                                             #
###############################################################################

#SRCS =     main_test.c Automated.c Basic.c Console.c CUCurses.c CUError.c  Cunit_intl.c \
#       MyMem.c TestDB.c TestRun.c Util.c wxWidget.c main_test.c \
#       $(TST_SRCS)

# define the C object files 
#
# This uses Suffix Replacement within a macro:
#   $(name:string1=string2)
#         For each word in 'name' replace 'string1' with 'string2'

OBJ = $(SRCS:%.c=%.o)

# define the C compiler to use
CC = gcc
# define any compile-time flags
ODIR = out
#compile and link
#CFLAGS = -O0 -g -Wall -fmessage-length=0 -fprofile-arcs -ftest-coverage            
#compile without link
CFLAGS = -O0 -c -Wall -fmessage-length=0 -fprofile-arcs -ftest-coverage         
#TODO Linkerflags
LFLAGS = --coverage 

#VPATH=test
#VPATH=source
# define the executable file,

TARGET = CUnit

export COVERAGE = $(TST_SRCS)
export STUBS = $(STUB_SRCS)

all: 

    $(MAKE) -C stub
    $(MAKE) -C source   

    @echo --- build finished ---
    @echo.
    @echo TODO
    @echo --- start linking ---
    @echo.
```

and makefile of subdirectory

```
# define any directories containing header files other than /usr/include
# TODO 

# define any libraries to link into executable:
#   if I want to link in libraries (libx.so or libx.a) I use the -llibname 
#   option, something like (this will link in libmylib.so and libm.so:
LIBS = 

#  TODO define the C source files
SRCS = $(COVERAGE) 

# define the C object files 
#
# This uses Suffix Replacement within a macro:
#   $(name:string1=string2)
#         For each word in 'name' replace 'string1' with 'string2'

OBJ = $(SRCS:%.c=%.o)

# define the C compiler to use
CC = gcc
# define any compile-time flags
ODIR = ../out
#compile without link
CFLAGS = -O0 -c -fmessage-length=0 -fprofile-arcs -ftest-coverage           
#TODO Linkerflags
LFLAGS = --coverage 

# define the executable file,


all: $(TARGET) $(OBJ)
    $(CC) $(OBJ) $(CFLAGS) -o $(TARGET) $(LFLAGS) $(OBJ) 

    @echo +++ build of source finished +++


clean:
        $(RM) *.o *~ $(MAIN)

# DO NOT DELETE THIS LINE -- make depend needs it
```

I it is easier for the linker, if all Output file are in the same Directory. Works this with ODIR?

Comment: You should use `-C` with sub-makefiles, this is easily manageable. You also should have one rule per source file in order to manage include dependencies

Comment: If gcc is called with -c there are no Output-files. How does the linking work in this case?

Comment: not `gcc -c`. `make -C`

Comment: In the makefile of the root Directory I`m using "make -C SUBDIRECTORY" this calls the makefiles in the subdirectory, but does not link the modules together. Maybee there is something missing.

Comment: You can't link the objects from your sub-makefiles if you need all of the subdirs to be compiled first. You have to do it in the highest makefile. I don't know anything about your file hierarchy so I can't help you more than that.

Comment: Yes, but with which command can I link them?
I have the root Directory and three sub-directories(test, source, stub).

Comment: Why do you need me to tell you the command? Don't you know how to link files to create an executable? What is your actual problem?

Answer (score 1):

With the compiler option `-c -g` I can compile each submake and link the object files together.

```
CFLAGS = -O0 -Wall -c -g -fmessage-length=0 -fprofile-arcs -ftest-coverage
```